# Jquery Mobile Hide and showing of a div doesn't work on mobile devices

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have got a footer in my screen .

Based on a condition i  need to hide or show this footer .
I am calling the below function to do this job .

This works in browser (desktop) , bu not in tablet .

This is page2.html

```
 $(document).on('click', '.pickitemshomesearch ', function(event)
  {
    var calledfrom = 'searchpage';
    $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", "index.html?UUID=" + UUID + '&screen_id=' + screen_id + '&cust_id=' + cust_id + '&minimum_order=' + minimum_order + '&addreslabel=' + addreslabel + '&accessedfrom=' + accessedfrom + '&tablenum=' + tablenum + '&redirectedfrom=' + redirectedfrom + '&seatnum=' + seatnum + '&row=' + row + '&calledfrom=' + calledfrom,
    {
        allowSamePageTransition: true,
        reload: true,
        transition: "none"
    });
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });
```

This is page1

```
    $(document).one('pagebeforeshow', '#customerpage', function(event)
 {
    $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
    var calledfrom = '';
    sessionlogic('generic');
 }); // ready ends 
 function sessionlogic()
 {
    displaylogicforfooter();
 }

 function displaylogicforfooter()
 {
    var myorders_quantityvalue = parseInt($(".myOrderPanel_footer .myorders").data('myorders'));
    if (myorders_quantityvalue >= 1)
    {
        $('.myOrderPanel_footer').show();
    }
    else
    {
        $('.myOrderPanel_footer').hide();
    }
    return false;
 }
```

Could you please tell me how to resolve this issue ??

Comment: When do you call `displaylogicforfooter` ?

Comment: there are two pages page1 and page2 , when navigated from page2 to page1

Answer (score 0):

The most common problem is in safari mobile `data()` method does not work, or almost does not work correctly. Use `dataset()` instead and it works. I was having this issue in iPad many times, and I resolve with that:

```
$(".myOrderPanel_footer .myorders").dataset.myorders;
```

Comment: there is no peoblem with the logic , its working fine in desktop , only the issue is with hide and showing of div's

Comment: If in mobile crash the data getter, the script don't continue to show/hide functions. Test it or almost debug your code and say where it crash. Show and hide works perfectly in mobile and desktop

Comment: okay but it passes this condition  if (myorders_quantityvalue >= 1) but showing of div is not working .

Comment: what value have got `myorders_quantityvalue`? If it's zero or less it hides forever and ever

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/wiqeba/edit?html,js,console,output

The variable myorders_quantityvalue is giving 0 even incase of desktop for me, I think that is the issue